# Rav Moshe's Chanuka additions to Baruch Hashem Yom Yom

Tags: shabbat, words, chanuka, shabbat-songs, moshe-feinstein

This morning in Shul I saw a pamphlet that said as follows. The song Boruch Hashem Yom Yom, the sixth stanza is referring to Chanuka. It said in this pamphlet that Rabbi Moshe Feinstein Zatzal would chant this song each Shabbos. However on the week of Chanuka he would add on "some well known words" when he got to this stanza. It mentioned that Rebetzin Small knew what these words were, however it did not elaborate what these words were? Does anyone know what Rabbi Moshe Feinstein Zatzal added on here?

translation from [ZemirotDatabase.org](http://www.zemirotdatabase.org/view_song.php?id=96)

> וּצְפִיר הָעִזִּים הִגְדִיל עֲצוּמָיו, וְגַם חָזוּת אַרְבַּע עָלוּ
>   לִמְרוֹמָיו, וּבְלִבָּם דִּמּוּ לְהַשְׁחִית אֶת רְחוּמָיו, עַל יְדֵי
>   כֹהֲנָיו מִגֵּר מִתְקוֹמְמָיו, חַסְדֵי ה׳ כּי לֹא תָמְנוּ כּי לֹא
>   כָלוּ רַחֲמָיו.
>
> When the he-goat waxed strong  And four notable ones came up against
>   God's heights,  Think​ing in their hearts to destroy His beloved, 
>   Then,​ by His priests (the Maccabaea​ns) He overthrew​ those who rose 
>   again​st Him,  It is of the Lord's mercies that we are not consumed,​
>   for His  compa​ssio​ns fail not.